# Quarkus: Disable Docker test containers?

Tags: docker, quarkus

I dusted off an old Java project implemented with Quarkus and updated the dependencies to Quarkus 2.4.0.  However, I've noticed that when I start the application it also fires up a Docker PostgreSQL container.  I have another DB for testing, so I don't need Quarkus to create one for me.  I couldn't locate any configuration properties to set in `application.properties` that would prevent this from being created.  Am I missing something?  Is there a flag somewhere that I need to set?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `quarkus.devservices.enabled=false` to disable all [DevServices](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services), or use the specific properties for each one - which in your case would be `quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=false`